# mp4 video cannot be played in Android VideoView and Mediaplayer

Tags: android, media-player, android-videoview, rtsp

I have indeed tried to check here and else were for solution to this but no luck, probably because am a newbee.

**TASK:** I want to play a `RTSP` video stream on an `android app`

**TRIALS:** I tried out with a `2min mp4` video copied to the `res\raw` folder with Media Player and `VideoView`. Later I used the `API Demo` sample and I set:

```
 path = "android.resourcee://com.me.mobile/R.raw.mithlat";
```

**ERROR:** 
on `MediaPlayer` API Demo just a blank page, no video no sound
on `VideoView` API Demo  it shows

```
"Sorry this video cannot be played"
```

CONFIG:
My target is `2.33` (This is what am testing with)

`minimun is 2.1`

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Video Streaming or Playing Video require too much power. Sometimes it will not play to emulator. try to Run it to your phone.

Try this code and Run this to your phone.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
setContentView(R.layout.main);
String videourl = "http://something.com/blah.mp4";
Uri uri = Uri.parse(videourl);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "video/mp4");
startActivity(intent);
}
```

Or [Click here to watch Android Video Streaming Tutorial](http://youtu.be/ZKsy81SmPFo).

Answer (score 1):

I know it a very late reply but for future references, I am adding this.

This is because path should be mentioned like this :
`"android.resource://" + getPackageName() +"/raw/" + mediaName"`, where media name is the name of video sample.

`R.raw.variableName/fileName` gives the int value references and should be with the Android's inbuilt functions like `getString(R.id.string_name)`, which return the exact resources in required formats.

Also, in this case, `VideoView` is not getting the proper media file that's why it is not able to run it and giving this error.

Answer (score 0):

Try the stream rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov. Type this in your browser and it will automatically open with the android native player. If this plays then you probably need to look at your stream once again. I dont have android 2.3 although i played the same url in android 3.2 and it worked. Also check the answer of [Playing a video in VideoView in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263736/playing-a-video-in-videoview-in-android) for you reference. Hope this helps you I guess android 2.3 does not support `rtsp` although not pretty sure. Try the url and check if it is playing

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code for playing Video in the videoView

```
VideoView videoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName()+"/"+ R.raw.demo7);
video.setVideoURI(uri);
video.start();
```

Comment: Please change "R.raw.demo7" to your respective video name