# Playing MyVideo Videos in VideoView?

Tags: java, android, video

How can I play a video of MyVideo in a VideoView? 
Or should I do this via iframe and webview?

`video.setVideoURI(Uri."the url");`

causes the app to say `Can't play video`

Can anyone give me an example?

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263736/playing-a-video-in-videoview-in-android?rq=1

Comment: but this is for a local video, not via URL

Comment: It suggests that it might be a compatibility issue. there are some formats that don't work with Android

Comment: so no chance to embed a myvideo video into the app? :/