# Displaying Video onclick of JSON object

Tags: android, json

I want to display a video for the app I am developing. The problem that I am facing is, I have a Button being displayed from a template which is in `JSON` format.
[layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOc1N.png) `Onclick` of this button I want my `main.xml` to be displayed. The contents of my XML are as follows.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Play Video"
    />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/playvideoplayer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="- PLAY Video -"
    />


<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/videoview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```

Could anyone please suggest how I could resolve this issue.

Comment: you wanted to display a layout or you need to display video on play video click.  can u please explain bit more ?

Comment: I need to display video on the click of the button "Play Video". You can view this button in the image that I have already mentioned. This button is getting displayed through the template. The template is as follows:   {
            "id": "play_video",
            "name_kn": "ವೀಡಿಯೊ ಆಡಲು",
            "server_action": {
                "url": "vd.3gp",
                "method": "post",
                "close_after_save": true
            },
            "type": "bt",
            "name": "Play Video",
            "mandatory": false
        },

Comment: This `json` string gets converted to android xml template?

Comment: @lisa, your question is bit puzzling, Kindly rephrase it.

Comment: onclick of the button I want to display the video. This button is being added in the template. I have already mentioned the template contents in the above contents.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263736/playing-a-video-in-videoview-in-android

Comment: I am unable to understand how to connect from JSON to XML. I am successfully able to play the video independently in Android. But I do not understand how I can connect a button in JSON to XML page