# Error when play video from internal storage with videoView

Tags: android, download, android-videoview, android-internal-storage

Im trying to download video file from server and save in a path, then play this video file by video play in an android application. Im using android studio. Downloading from server and saving  in below path successfully was done.

```
  "/data/data/"  + getPackageName() +  "/raw/" + "video1_3"
```

But when i address the videoview to this path to play the video, the app crash.

```
    videoPlayer = findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    videoPlayer.setVideoPath("/data/data/" + getPackageName() + "/raw/" + "video1_3");
    videoPlayer.start();
```

I checked the file in this path and Im sure that the downloaded file is there. but I couldn't play file from this directory. 
Could you please help me
thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3263736/8383332) question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Playing a video in VideoView in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263736/playing-a-video-in-videoview-in-android)

Comment: Thanks @SoonSantos, I answered my question

Comment: Thanks @s_t, my problem was different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could figure out my problem. It was very stupid and delicate point. The point is that I forgot to add the file format and I should include file format to the end of file name.
Therefore, I changed this line:

```
      videoPlayer.setVideoPath("/data/data/" + getPackageName() + "/raw/" + video1_3");
```

to:

```
      videoPlayer.setVideoPath("/data/data/" + getPackageName() + "/raw/" + "video1_3.mp4");
```

Then the code work well for me.