# Android : Copy RawFile to Sdcard (video mp4)

Tags: java, android, video, android-sdcard

What is wrong on this code ?
I've a Raw file in my project (mp4 videofile),
when i do this, and then i retreive file from SDcard file are not identical so video can not be load :(
Do you have another way to automaticly copy a raw file to sdcard ?
Thanks

```
String FICHIER_BLOW = "blowvid4.mp4";
File f=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), FICHIER_BLOW);
try {
    if (f.createNewFile()){
    FileWriter ecrivain = new FileWriter(f);
    BufferedWriter bufEcrivain = new BufferedWriter(ecrivain);
    BufferedInputStream VideoReader = new BufferedInputStream(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.blow));
    while( VideoReader.available() > 0 ){
        bufEcrivain.write(VideoReader.read());
    }
    bufEcrivain.close();

    VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
    MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
    video =Uri.fromFile(f);
    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
    videoView.setVideoURI(video);
    videoView.start();
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you use an InputStream to read, use an OutputStream to write, i.e. a BufferedOutputStream-wrapped FileOutputStream. Also, your code is pretty inefficient, as it only copies one byte at a time. I'd suggest creating a byte array buffer and using these relevant read/write methods:

```
int BufferedInputStream.read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int length)
void BufferedOutputStream.write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int length)
```

Comment: As per softam's note, you may need an extra flush() -- definitely in the case of BufferedOutputStream

Answer (score 7):

It works,thanks

```
BufferedOutputStream bufEcrivain = new BufferedOutputStream((new FileOutputStream(f)));
BufferedInputStream VideoReader = new BufferedInputStream(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.blow));
byte[] buff = new byte[32 * 1024];
int len;
while( (len = VideoReader.read(buff)) > 0 ){
    bufEcrivain.write(buff,0,len);
}
bufEcrivain.flush();
bufEcrivain.close();
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should flush before you close the stream

```
bufEcrivain.flush();
bufEcrivain.close();
```

Comment: According to the docs, BufferedWriter.close() automatically flushes. Not the case for BufferedOutputStream though (again, according to the docs).