# Wants to play mp4 video from assets folder in android

Tags: android, mp4, assets

I want to play mp4 video which is available in my assets/raw folder.
I am successfully playing mp4 video from my sd card but not able to get video from assets folder or from raw folder.

Comment: could you give your code please? maybe the path you are using is not right coz it should work the same way

Answer (score 1):

As I said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028717/how-to-play-videos-in-android-from-assets-folder-or-raw-folder/3537114#3537114), your issue might come from the size of the data if it is compressed :

> Hi guys,  If I remember well, I had
>   the same kind of issue when loading
>   stuff from the asset folder but with a
>   database. It seems that the stuff in
>   your asset folder can have 2 stats :
>   compressed or not.   If it is
>   compressed, then you are allowed 1 Mo
>   of memory to uncompress it, otherwise
>   you will get this kind of exception.
>   There are [several bug reports](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3122)
>   about that because the documentation
>   is not clear. So if you still want to
>   to use your format, you have to either
>   use an uncompressed version, or give
>   an extension like .mp3 or .png to your
>   file. I know it's a bit crazy but I
>   load a database with a .mp3 extension
>   and it works perfectly fine. This
>   other solution is to package your
>   application with a special option to
>   tell it not to compress certain
>   extension. But then you need to build
>   your app manually and add "zip -0"
>   option.   The advantage of an
>   uncompressed assest is that the phase
>   of zip-align before publication of an
>   application will align the data
>   correctly so that when loaded in
>   memory it can be directly mapped.
>
> ### So, solutions :
>
> - change the extension of the file to .mp3 or .png and see if it works
> - build your app manually and use the zip-0 option