# Trying to play video from raw folder (VideoView)

Tags: android

I can play a video from the Internet by inserting the URL like below:

```
mPath   = Uri.parse("http://commonsware.com/misc/test2.3gp");
mVid.setVideoURI(mPath);
mVid.requestFocus();
mVid.start();
```

But now I have a video in my raw folder so the path is res/raw/testing.3gp.  The code below doesn't work, and I've tried some other ways too to no avail.

```
mPath   = Uri.parse("../../res/raw/testing.3gp");
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: okay...I found the code that I had working before with different video, but it is not working now.
mPath = Uri.parse("android:resource://com.example.wordweather/" + R.raw.scott);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to play videos in android from assets folder or raw folder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028717/how-to-play-videos-in-android-from-assets-folder-or-raw-folder)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I had the same problem.
This worked for me:

```
Uri video = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.pac.myapp/raw/master");
```

So as you see you have 3 parts of the uri:

1. `android.resource://`
2. `com.pac.myapp`
3. `/raw/master`

`master` is the name of your video

Comment: I wish I could mark this as the correct answer. This helped me so much!! Thank you.

Comment: That didn't work for me.. I got the dreaded 'this video could not be played error'.  What did work however was Uri url = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.calvium.myApp/" + R.raw.video); (where my video resource was called 'video.3gp'.

Comment: This solution worked for me. However, I'm suspicious about it working on any other OS versions/devices - i.e. there's been loads of people who reported the "R.raw.*" version to be working instead. Can anyone elaborate as to what one could expect from VideoView?

Comment: More on this topic. http://javatech.org/2011/01/discovering-android-embedding-video-in-an-android-application/

Answer (score 6):

this works for me

```
 String videoName = nameWithoutFileExtention;

 int id = getResources().getIdentifier(videoName, "raw", getActivity().getPackageName());

 final String path = "android.resource://" + getActivity().getPackageName() + "/" + id;

 vvBgVideo.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button btn=(Button)this.findViewById(R.id.playvideo);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                VideoView vid=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.video);
                vid.setMediaController(new MediaController(MainActivity.this));
                Uri video = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.tenzinthinley.video/raw/ed");
                vid.setVideoURI(video);
                vid.requestFocus();
                vid.start();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Change my name if this doesn't works. 'ed' is the video file name.

Answer (score -1):

You just need to locate song in raw folder under resource folder.
if it is link then

```
 private String urlVideo ="http://www.pocketjourney.com/downloads/pj/video/famous.3gp";

    //Make uri from song located in raw folder
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/"
                + R.raw.shakebooty);
        player.setUpVideoFrom(uri.toString());

        public void setUpVideoFrom(String source) throws IllegalArgumentException,
                IllegalStateException, IOException {

            mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

//Only to check if you want to play song from url
            if (source.contains("http"))
            {
            mPlayer.setDataSource(source);
            }
//If want to play song from uri you created from song in raw folder
        else {
             mPlayer.setDataSource(ctx, source);
             }

        }
```

Enjoy playing video in surface view