# Media is not playing from raw folder

Tags: android

i have the following code:

```
animalGallery.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                            int arg2, long arg3) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        animalView.setImageResource(symbolIds[arg2]);

String imageName = getResources().getResourceEntryName(
                            symbolIds[arg2]);

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), imageName,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    int audioId = getResources().getIdentifier(
                            imageName, null, getPackageName());


                        try {
                            MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(
                                getApplicationContext(), audioId);

                        mp.start();

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "not working", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                    }
                });
```

When i run this code then i am getting correct `imageName`.

All My mp3 files are in `raw` folder.

i want to play mp3 file according to imagename.

```
suppose imageName='hardweell" then the hardweell.mp3 is must be play
```

The media is not playing. It is going to catch every time.

So how can i solve this issue?

Below is logs where file is crashed:

```
01-12 18:01:55.518: I/View(26260): Touch down dispatch to android.widget.ImageView{42813e88 VFED.... ..S..... 0,0-450,200}, event = MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, id[0]=0, x[0]=101.81146, y[0]=115.70969, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=20852614, downTime=20852614, deviceId=3, source=0x1002 }
01-12 18:01:55.524: I/View(26260): Touch down dispatch to android.widget.Gallery{42761308 VFED.... ......I. 0,0-450,200 #7f09000e app:id/animalGallery}, event = MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, id[0]=0, x[0]=101.81146, y[0]=115.70969, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=20852614, downTime=20852614, deviceId=3, source=0x1002 }
01-12 18:01:55.526: D/VelocityTracker(26260): Couldn't open '/dev/touch' (Permission denied)
01-12 18:01:55.526: D/VelocityTracker(26260): tpd read x fail: Bad file number
01-12 18:01:55.526: D/VelocityTracker(26260): tpd read y fail: Bad file number
01-12 18:01:55.602: I/View(26260): Touch up dispatch to android.widget.Gallery{42761308 VFED.... ......I. 0,0-450,200 #7f09000e app:id/animalGallery}, event = MotionEvent { action=ACTION_UP, id[0]=0, x[0]=101.81146, y[0]=115.70969, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=20852703, downTime=20852614, deviceId=3, source=0x1002 }
01-12 18:01:55.603: V/Provider/Settings(26260):  from settings cache , name = sound_effects_enabled , value = 0
01-12 18:01:55.612: W/ResourceType(26260): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
01-12 18:01:55.629: D/GraphicBuffer(26260): create handle(0x60e6f328) (w:544, h:960, f:1)
01-12 18:01:55.634: D/OpenGLRenderer(26260): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 540.00, 960.00) opaque 1 <0x616f2f80>
01-12 18:01:55.635: D/OpenGLRenderer(26260): finish <0x616f2f80>
01-12 18:01:55.685: D/GraphicBuffer(26260): create handle(0x60e74e70) (w:112, h:66, f:1)
01-12 18:01:58.045: D/dalvikvm(26260): threadid=11: exiting
01-12 18:01:58.045: D/dalvikvm(26260): threadid=11: bye!
01-12 18:01:59.114: D/GraphicBuffer(26260): close handle(0x60e74e70) (w:112 h:66 f:1)
01-12 18:01:59.173: D/GraphicBuffer(26260): create handle(0x61d828a8) (w:144, h:66, f:1)
01-12 18:02:02.618: D/GraphicBuffer(26260): close handle(0x61d828a8) (w:144 h:66 f:1)
01-12 18:02:34.102: D/ActivityThread(26260): ACT-AM_ON_PAUSE_CALLED ActivityRecord{426311c8 token=android.os.BinderProxy@426309e0 {com.example.kidzgk/com.example.kidzgk.AnimalsLearnPage}}
01-12 18:02:34.122: D/ActivityThread(26260): ACT-PAUSE_ACTIVITY handled : 0 / android.os.BinderProxy@426309e0
01-12 18:02:34.124: D/ActivityThread(26260): ACT-STOP_ACTIVITY_SHOW handled : 0 / android.os.BinderProxy@426309e0
01-12 18:02:34.131: V/InputMethodManager(26260): START INPUT: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{426324a8 V.E..... R....... 0,0-540,960} ic=null tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@428d09d0 controlFlags=#100
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trying to play video from raw folder (VideoView)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3609219/trying-to-play-video-from-raw-folder-videoview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If file is inside `raw` folder then prepare media player by passing video id using `R.raw.<filename>` as:

```
int audioId = getResources().getIdentifier(imageName, null, getPackageName());
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),audioId);
```

Comment: @siddharth: post log with question probably you are passing wrong id for file

Comment: Oh.. yes i got the wrong. Images are in different folder and media files are in different folder.

Comment: @siddharth: post log with question when application is crashing

Comment: @siddharth: you are saying application is get crashed show add log with question

Comment: see i have add the log cat where application is crashed.

Comment: @siddharth: what you are getting `int audioId = getResources().getIdentifier(imageName, null, getPackageName());` ?

Comment: i am getting id like "8746363"