# make a specific song in the Notification

Tags: java, android, notifications

Is it possible to make a song from the raw folder starts when i receive a notification?
I tried this code to make the song "alert" starts but nothing happen.

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
        .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.beatdanger,
        "Your friend is in danger!!!", System.currentTimeMillis());
// Hide the notification after its selected
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

notification.sound = Uri.parse("R.raw.alert");


Intent intent1 = new Intent("wael.ilahi.pfe.SMSRECEIVERESULT");
intent1.putExtra("coordination", str);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
        intent1, 0);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "Help your friend !!",
        str, pendingIntent);
notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

Comment: Work on your accept-rate. Also, there should be some kind of error or exception-message in the LogCat. Add it to your question.

Comment: No there is no error in the LogCat

Comment: yes i check it but nothing happen and no error show up in the LogCat

Comment: What file-type is your sound, what have you put as your URI, have you logged the URI-path to the Log-Cat and manually checked if the desired file can be found there?

Answer (score 1):

See the "Adding a sound"-chapter in the [Android Documentation for Notifications](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Sound).

Your problem seems to be, that you're giving the `notification`-object a wrong URI: `"R.raw.alert"` is not valid.

Instead, if you need to get an URI to a file stored in the `res/raw/`-directory, use this pattern: `"android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.your_raw_file` as explained here: [How to play videos in android from assets folder or raw folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8616187/717341)