# Android cannot play video in videoview

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, debugging

I am a 11 year old coder and I am getting this error on my phone when I try to run the video view code so I can play a video.
The error is,"Sorry, this video cannot be played." My video I downloaded was in the raw folder under resources and the code and xml are all fine. The video format of which I am using is a mp4. Heres my code:

```
package com.example.lenovouser.video;


import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    VideoView videoView = findViewById(R.id.video_view);

    Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.green_and_yellow_popsicle);
    videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
    videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
    videoView.start();


}
```

}

And here is my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.lenovouser.video.MainActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/video_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</FrameLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: I uptated my question.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see the extension of the video file.  I am not sure if you can play any video from the raw, instead can you please create a assets folder an place the video file there.

```
videoView.setVideoPath("file:///assets/myvideo.mp4");  
videoView.start();
```

Also make sure you are using the video format specified in the android support documentation: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats#recommendations

Comment: The OP is using Raw folder, where did you get drawable from? The R.raw does not show the extension afaik

Comment: Hi, the video is in the raw folder, not the drawable

Comment: I am not using the drawable folder for the video

Answer (score 0):

try using this instead this uses the raw URI instead of R.raw
check this post if you are still having trouble [How to play video from raw folder with Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15675944/how-to-play-video-from-raw-folder-with-android-device)

```
String videoPath = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/raw/green_and_yellow_popsicle";
videoView.start();
```

how ever if you still wanna use R.raw use the code below,

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.green_and_yellow_popsicle);
videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
videoView.start();
```

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work for, me- still said the same error

Comment: It's not in the log it's in the phone.. thats the error thats showing:

Comment: There is a stacktrace, look in the logcat there should be a reason of why it isn't playing

Comment: the log is fine

Comment: what is a stacktrace?

Comment: Are you using android studio?

Comment: Yes I am, I am using android studio

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your phone`s API level under 4.1 or try another video with different format.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

None of these solutions worked for me, but here you can found out how to get an URI  from **R.raw** folder: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8616187/8187578