# What is solution when VideoView can not find video from raw directory?

Tags: android, android-videoview

I am learning android developing. In `VideoView` everything is okay but video can not find from the `raw` directory which I made already. Please check my screenshot.

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImjKi.png)

Comment: Double Check if you have imported the right R file . In edition try Invalidate and restart AS.

Comment: Did you rebuild your project after adding that raw file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to play video from raw folder with Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15675944/how-to-play-video-from-raw-folder-with-android-device)

Answer (score 0):

Copy Video to Assets Folder, Then

```
   String path = "file:///android_asset/video.mp4";
   videoview.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
```

Comment: It's working but after installing running apk this show "can't play this video" please help.

Answer (score 0):

The name of video must be in small letter and rebulid the project for AS detect the video and can load on the videoPath.

In Capital letter AS send message error when you rebuild the project.

This can resolved the problem.