# How to convert android resource path to string

Tags: java, android, android-videoview

This is my video view class and its working fine

```
private void CopyReadVdo() {
    setContentView(R.layout.video_player);
    VideoView view = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoview);
    String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.video1;
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);
    view.setVideoURI(uri);
    MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(view);
    view.setMediaController(mediaController);
    view.start();
}
```

I need to call this function with an argument like

```
private void CopyReadVdo(String vdoname) {
    setContentView(R.layout.video_player);

    VideoView view = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoview);
    String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + vdoname;
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);
    view.setVideoURI(uri);
    MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(view);
    view.setMediaController(mediaController);
    view.start();
}
```

but is shows error **Can't play this video**. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the video format can you show the video file name?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to play video from raw folder with Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15675944/how-to-play-video-from-raw-folder-with-android-device)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try to get resource id `rawId` from resource name `vdoname`

```
int rawId = getResources().getIdentifier(vdoname,  "raw", getPackageName());
String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + rawId;
```

**Update:**
pass `shaktee` as `vdoname` to `CopyReadVdo` function instead of `R.raw.shaktee`

Or change type of `vdoname` to int and pass `R.raw.shaktee` to `CopyReadVdo` function

```
private void CopyReadVdo(int vdoname) {
    setContentView(R.layout.video_player);

    VideoView view = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoview);
    String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + vdoname;
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);
    view.setVideoURI(uri);
    MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(view);
    view.setMediaController(mediaController);
    view.start();
}
```

Comment: It does not get raw id. Does it show rawId is 0. if it needs permission in manifest?

Comment: What do you pass in `vdoname`?

Comment: CopyReadVdo("R.raw.shaktee")

Comment: Just pass `shaktee` instead of `R.raw.shaktee`. `getResources().getIdentifier` do the rest for you

Comment: It's working with CopyReadVdo("shaktee").. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

Try below code

```
Uri video = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.sample/raw/filename");
```