# Where to put the Video file in android Project

Tags: android, android-layout, video, android-videoview

I have a  video, I need to know where to place and how to get the path of that video.

I know how to add the video form URL,

```
 Uri uri=Uri.parse("www.abc.com/myVid.mp4");
        videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
```

This works fine, but now the video file is in my project, I need to know how to get the path from the folder structure

Kindly guide me.

Thanks

Comment: Are you planning to bundle the video with the app? Or download it once the app opens?

Comment: use assets for that

Comment: i want to bundle video with the app

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028717/how-to-play-videos-in-android-from-assets-folder-or-raw-folder

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> You can create asset folder inside your project and store your video in that folder.

Then you can get that using `getAssets()` function which is provided by `Android`.

**EDIT 1:**

You can click on the Project window, press Alt-Insert, and select Folder -> Assets Folder. Android Studio will add it automatically to the correct location.

Also, you can do this.

```
VideoView view = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);
String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.video_file;
view.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
view.start();
```

Where `video_file` is your file name.

Comment: Thanks! Where to create `asset` folder? Inside `res` folder?

Answer (score 9):

You can Create a folder under Resources and Name it raw. Then to provide the Path to the Video you can simply do

```
 String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/"
            + R.raw.intro_land;
```

and then

```
  videoplayer.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
```

Answer (score 4):

You can view your own video by creating a folder under `res` as follows:

- Right click on `res` -> `New` -> `Android Resource Directory`
- select Resource type as `raw`

[image: New Resource Directory]

Then you can upload your video into this directory.

```
VideoView videoView = videoViewFragment.findViewById(R.id.videoView);
String path = "android.resource://" + getActivity().getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.video01;
herevideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path)); 
videoView.start();
```

`video01` is your mp4 file name

Answer (score 1):

You can create raw folder under res and put your video there,

Check [this](http://androidexample.com/Play_Video_File_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=124&aaid=144)

```
VideoView mVideoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoview);

                    String uriPath = "android.resource://com.android.AndroidVideoPlayer/"+R.raw.k;

                    Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriPath);
                    mVideoView.setVideoURI(uri);
                    mVideoView.requestFocus();
                    mVideoView.start();
```