# iOS & Android: Is it possible to save videos directly to the app's bundle?

Tags: android, ios, video, embed, offline

My understanding is that some assets within apps (like the the splash screen) can be shown right from the start / when the user opens the app for the first time because they are bundled together with the app build. Is that also the case with videos? We need some videos within the onboarding tour to be available right away, also when in offline mode.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is yes, you can store videos this way. You put your video in a folder named 'raw' user the resources folder.

See here for some examples: [Where to put the Video file in android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38612506/334402)

However, video are very large so you may exceed you target app size.

You also will have to update your app if you want to update the video.

Streaming the video would avoid these issues, but you do have to have connectivity.

One compromised might be to have a small simple looked video for quick start up an offline, and switch to a streamed video as soon as it is available after startup.