# i will load all video from raw and show with media player

Tags: android, mediastore

**I will load all video from raw folder and show it with mediaplayr. for this use following code but get Exception. what is wrong?
thanks**

```
String filePath = "android.resource://" + this.getPackageName() + "/raw/";
ContentResolver resolver=getContentResolver();
String projection[]=  {MediaStore.Video.Media._ID,MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION};
Cursor cursor= resolver.query(MediaStore.Video.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI ,projection, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA+ "='"+filePath+"'", null, null);

     videoDetails=new ArrayList<VideoInfo>();
     while(cursor.moveToNext())
     {
        int id=cursor.getInt(0);
        String title=cursor.getString(1);
        int dur=cursor.getInt(2);
        videoDetails.add(new VideoInfo(id,title,dur));

     }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to play videos in android from assets folder or raw folder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028717/how-to-play-videos-in-android-from-assets-folder-or-raw-folder)

Answer (score 0):

You can play the videos from raw using this function

```
String  UrlPath="android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.ur_file_name;
videocontainer.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(UrlPath));
videocontainer.start();
```

Code taken from *bishop Fakhry* From here [how-to-play-videos-in-android-from-assets-folder-or-raw-folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028717/how-to-play-videos-in-android-from-assets-folder-or-raw-folder)

Comment: but with this code i can load just one file . i have more than 30 file and will create a dynamic code to load all files from the raw foldr