# How to load video from assets folder to video view?

Tags: android, android-videoview, android-assets

I have a sub folder inside the assets folder named alphabets. Now I am aware that i can use raw folder instead, but that method doesnt allow me to create sub folder inside raw folder. So i would like to experiment using assets folder instead. I have many videos to load to the videoview that's why i would want it to be as organized as possible.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8457098/115145 https://stackoverflow.com/a/7195696/115145

Comment: on the first link, i didnt quite understood the "player.setDataSource(
    getAssets().openFd(**"media/video.mp4"**).getFileDescriptor()
);"

I think that one is different from what I wanted to implement with the videoView

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to play videos in android from assets folder or raw folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028717/how-to-play-videos-in-android-from-assets-folder-or-raw-folder)